# Create an Azure storage account name with concatenated variables in Terraform

Tags: variables, terraform, azure-storage, string-concatenation, azure-storage-account

We have a requirement to create an Azure storage account in Terraform. However, the naming convention required is to combine three declared variables, meaning the module will look something like the below:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name    = "(var.first)(var.second)(var.third)"
  resource_group_name      = "rg01"
  location                 = "uksouth"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
```

It's become a bit of a struggle trying to achieve this and having pored over the Terraform guides, there doesn't appear to be any function that can enable us achieve this. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use format():

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name    = format("%s%s%s", var.first, var.second, var.third)
  resource_group_name      = "rg01"
  location                 = "uksouth"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
```

Comment: Abinet, apologies for the accidental downvote. Tried undoing it but kept getting the error message that my vote is currently locked and I can only do so if your answer is edited.

Comment: @hitman126 I will upvote to compensate for that:-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your variables are strings and you don't have any incorrect characters, then it should be:

```
name    = "${var.first}${var.second}${var.third}"
```

Comment: Both, your response is much appreciated. You might also want to know that shortly after 
 my post, I went on to try this other implementation and that worked perfectly too: 

```name    = format("%s", "${var.sa_1}${var.sa_2}${var.sa_3}")
```

Comment: Also, just to add that I tried both options presented by Marcin and Abinet and they do work, although I can only mark one as the answer, when in actual fact both should be.